# String/Binary data to Bytes

Tags: python, binary, bytebuffer, arrays

Am new to Python. I want to convert a char array to byte buffer i.e. Is there any way to convert data which could be string or binary data to  byte buffer.

Eg: if `str = 'apple'` I need buffer = bytes values of `'apple'` which I can access like `buffer[i]` and `buffer[:j]`

If i use `map(ord,'apple')` this returns a list but I need a continuos buffer. How do I get this in Python ?

**UPDATE 1:** Also I need in bytes because today it might be strings but tomorrow I might be dealing with files.

**UPDATE 0:** I want it in bytes. I could have used strings as @ignacio suggests but strings just wont do. Because eventually this will go into my implementation of rolling hash

Comment: What's wrong with slicing the string?

Comment: i want it in bytes. strings just wont do. because eventually this will go into my implementation of rolling hash.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.x then that's important information that needs to go into the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#bytearray). Which will convert the source string to an array of byte. There is an optional encoding parameter which you need to specify in case if the [default encoding](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-methods) is not the current default string encoding.

Example

```
>>> s = 'apple'
>>> arr=bytearray(s)
>>> [x for x in arr]
[97, 112, 112, 108, 101]
>>> type(arr)
<type 'bytearray'>
>>>
```

Comment: abhijit, thanks for reply. But i dont want the bytes in a list. I want it in a buffer. If I wanted it in a list I could have used `ord` itself. But later I might want to convert a file to bytes. In this scenario a byte buffer will make sense. It answers all my usecases. So how do I get this in a buffer instead of a list ?

Comment: Its not a list but an array. Just see the type of the variable created. I have used the list comprehension to just list of the content but its stored as a byte array. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Is bytearray just like a buffer. can I do `arr[i]` etc ?

Comment: yes you can. You can access the individual elements by indexing and also bytearray is mutable i.e. you can assign values to individual indexed element.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module in python.

> The struct module includes functions for converting between strings of
>   bytes and native Python data types such as numbers and strings.